# Почему не работают позиционные выделения в map?

Tags: nginx

```
map $request_uri $request_uri_path {
    ~^([^?]*) $1;
}
```

nginx: [emerg] unknown "1" variable

При этом именованное выделение работает:

```
map $request_uri $request_uri_path {
    ~^(?<match>[^?]*) $match;
}
```

> Регулярное выражение может содержать именованные и позиционные
>   выделения

[Документация](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html)

Comment: Вообще похоже на баг. Но вряд ли кто это будет чинить. Там много разного весёлого, например эти регулярки неочевидным образом влияют на rewrite. См. https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/564 и аналогичные баги

Answer (score 0):

> Регулярное выражение может содержать именованные и позиционные
>   выделения, которые могут затем использоваться в других директивах
>   совместно с результирующей переменной.

Т.е. формально документация не обещает возможность использования позиционных выделений в качестве результирующего значения, речь только про "другие директивы".